# What are the last four tokens of Python 3.5 grammar?

Tags: python, parsing, grammar, python-3.5

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/token.html

What are last four tokens about in the token definition of Python 3.5 grammar?

Comment: If you are referring to token.OP, token.ERRORTOKEN, token.N_TOKENS, and token.NT_OFFSET, then you should name those tokens in your question, so that it still makes sense if the page you linked to later changes.

Comment: Did you *"Refer to the file `Grammar/Grammar` in the Python distribution for the definitions of the names in the context of the language grammar"*?

Comment: You can see how tokens are used by tokenizing some code and printing the output of token assignments by code line/column as shown in the last example at https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html.

Comment: @TrisNefzger It takes a lot of trial & error though to get `ERRORTOKEN` and to figure out that you can’t find those last two ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### token.OP

Is a generalization of the operator tokens. This is also mentioned in the [tokenize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) module:

> To simplify token stream handling, all Operators and Delimiters tokens are returned using the generic `token.OP` token type. The exact type can be determined by checking the `exact_type` property on the named tuple returned from `tokenize.tokenize()`.

#### token.ERRORTOKEN

Is used to mark errors within the tokenize-process of the parser. This is mostly used to generate syntax errors that [abort the parsing process](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b339a35e2e77/Parser/parsetok.c#l208).

It’s also mentioned in the [tokenize documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.TokenError):

> Note that unclosed single-quoted strings do not cause an error to be raised. They are tokenized as `ERRORTOKEN`, followed by the tokenization of their contents.

#### token.N_TOKENS

Is simply the number of tokens that are defined. It’s used in the parser for iterating over the list of tokens.

#### token.NT_OFFSET

Is used in `token.h` like this:

```c
/* Special definitions for cooperation with parser */
#define NT_OFFSET       256

#define ISTERMINAL(x)       ((x) < NT_OFFSET)
#define ISNONTERMINAL(x)    ((x) >= NT_OFFSET)
```

It basically separates [terminal and non-terminal tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_and_nonterminal_symbols).